# Rails 5 How to get response of Ajax api call from coffee script file into a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

In my movies.coffee file I have this code which is making an ajax call to get a list of movies.

```
$.ajax 
url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=someapikey',
success: (data) ->
     response = data
```

I would then like to get the json response from the call into some kind of ruby object which I can then loop through and display it's contents on the movies.index.html.erb page in multiple bootstrap cards.

For example into an @movies instance variable, where I can call @movies.title, @movies.genre and so on.

I can't append the api data into the bootstrap card because I have other data that will be displayed there as well.

Comment: Since you already pulled the data via frontend why dont you also parse it there? What you intend to do is `view` -> `controller` -> `parse`  -> `controller` -> `view`. You could pull it in the rails controller itself and then assign it to `@movies`  and then render you movie index with it or parse it directly via coffeescript into the view.

Comment: It would be a security risk if the frontend -- after rendering -- could access and change ruby code. So the only way is to submit it back to your backend with another ajax request. So the question becomes: Why are you loading it in the frontend if you want to process it in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, You can use your controller index method for the same.
you can make

```
begin
    @movies = RestClient.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=someapikey')
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => err
    @movies = nil
    @errors = err.response
end
```

you will get your data in @movies variable and then you can populate it on html

Comment: One of the requirements is to make it an 'Ajax call' to fetch a list of movies. I think this is just making an http request.

Comment: you'll have to send the ajax request to controller's method with dataType: 'js' , get the data in it by calling this api parse the data and then you can append the parsed data using js.erb.